# How to read a pdf file stored in sdcard using mupdf reader stored in android device

Tags: java, android

Hi i am working on making an app in android that reads pdf from some given url and then store it in sdcard and then open it with mupdf reader that is in my android device.

I am getting the following error in my logcat :

logcat :

```
 02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ohile.openpdf/com.ohile.openpdf.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/pdf/Read.pdf typ=application/pdf }
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/pdf/Read.pdf typ=application/pdf }
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at com.ohile.openpdf.MainActivity.showPdf(MainActivity.java:46)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at com.ohile.openpdf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        02-15 05:47:10.276: E/AndroidRuntime(3134):     ... 11 more
```

i wrote following java code :

**DownloadFile.java **

```
public class DownloadFile {
    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory)  {
        try {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            URL u = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte []buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while((len = in.read(buffer))>0) {
                f.write(buffer,0,len);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        DownloadFile.downloadFile("http://14.140.41.194/monali/i.pdf",
                file);

        showPdf();
    }

     public void showPdf()
     {
         File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Read.pdf");
         PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
         Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
         List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
         intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
         startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

Can someone help me out where is the error in my code. ???

Comment: Did you register ACTION_VIEW in your manifest for MainActivity?

Comment: Also, tread *carefully*. muPDF is GPL licensed, so you'll need to make your source code available and attribute your viewer -- unless you've obtained a commercial license from Artifex. Legal minefield.

Comment: no i dint .how can i register this??

Comment: http://artifex.com/ -- pricey.

Comment: now i am facing the new problem.pdf got downloaded into my external storage.from there i can open the pdf ,but i need to open pdf within my app not by going to the external storage .

Comment: Then simply download it to internal storage: Instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory()` use `getFilesDir()`

Comment: why it is taking more time to show "complete action using" pop up on the app.its taking 15 to 20 seconds to show the pop up.why???

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/example.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```